# How to get the data from SharePoint library above 5000 items with pagination in SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, spfx, spfx-webparts

How to get the data from SharePoint library above 5000 items with pagination in SPFx?

Current code I am using:

```
const [PublishDocument, setPublishDocument] = useState([]);

 const PublishedDocument = async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);

      let useremail = props.context.pageContext.user.email;
      console.log(useremail);

      const response = await props.context.spHttpClient.get(
        props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
          `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('PublishedDocument')/items?$top=4999&$select=*,EncodedAbsUrl&$filter=DocumentType ne null and AuthorName ne null`,
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
        {
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata",
            "odata-version": "",
          },
        }
      );

      if (response.ok) {
        const responseJSON = await response.json();

        responseJSON.value.forEach((item: any) => {
          setPublishDocument((prevFriends): any => [
            ...prevFriends,
            {
              ID: item.ID,
              GuidData: item.RUID,
              OrignalID: item.OrignalID,
              OLDTagID: item.OldTagId,
              DocumentID: item.DocID,
              DocumentName: item.DocumentName,
              DocName: item.DocName,
              DocumentType: item.DocumentType,
              SubmissionDate: item.Created,
              RequestedBy: item.AuthorName,
              Version: item.RevisionNo,
              PublishDocument: item.DocName,
              IsPageNumberAdded: item.IsPageNumberAdded,

              // new download
              PublishDocument2:
                props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
                `/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=` +
                item.EncodedAbsUrl,
            },
          ]);
          setPublishDocument2((prevFriends): any => [
            ...prevFriends,
            {
              downloadpath:
                props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
                `/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=` +
                item.EncodedAbsUrl,
            },
          ]);
        });

        // -----------------Re-loader-------------------
        setIsLoading(false);
        checkAuthorReviewerPublisher();
        // checkAdmin();
      } else {
        const responseJSON = await response.json();
        // -----------------Re-loader-------------------
        setIsLoading(false);
        alert(`Something went wrong! Check the error in the browser console.`);
        console.log(responseJSON);
        checkAuthorReviewerPublisher();
        // checkAdmin();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setIsLoading(false);
      checkAuthorReviewerPublisher();
      // checkAdmin();
    }
  };
```